# Как правильно перебрать массив и положить данные в новый?

Tags: php, php7

Есть небольшой массив. Скажите, как проверить его элементы на часы работы т.е. если start-work и end-work совпадают, то в новый массив добавить часы работы, день недели и вывести это все на экран?

Проблема заключается в том, что я не знаю как выбранные элементы в новый массив в виде объекта.

```
$arr = [
        { "day_number": 1, "start-work": "12-00", "end-work": "15-00", "day": "Пн" },
        { "day_number": 2, "start-work": "12-00", "end-work": "15-00", "day": "Вт" },
        { "day_number": 3, "start-work": "12-00", "end-work": "13-00", "day": "Ср" },
        { "day_number": 4, "start-work": "12-00", "end-work": "13-00", "day": "Чт" },
        { "day_number": 5, "start-work": "11-00", "end-work": "12-00", "day": "Пт" },
        { "day_number": 6, "start-work": "8-00", "end-work": "9-00", "day": "Сб" },
        { "day_number": 7, "start-work": "7-00", "end-work": "6-00", "day": "Вс" }
       ];
```

Comment: это некорректный синтаксис. в php такого нет

Comment: в целом достаточяно одного цикла,  одного if и push в новый массив

Comment: это json объект, который приходит. Скажите, как мне его правильно добавить в новый массив и потом вывести?

Comment: json строка декодится в ассоциативный массив через `json_decode($arr, true);`  дальше как я написал выше

Comment: я это знаю. Подскажите, как мне правильно положить его в новый массив? Вся проблема у меня именно в том что я не знаю как добавить значения совпадающих и потом вывести

Comment: `$newArr[] = $element[$i]`

Comment: *если start-work и end-work совпадают* - они нигде не совпадают

Comment: они совпадают .

Comment: `"start-work": "12-00", "end-work": "15-00"` --- где тут они совпадают?